# How to display Different tables or blocks of data on the same row (level) in HTML

Tags: html, css, tabular

I need to display some data on a browser but I want to split the page into two sections. Thus I want to show the second table next to the other rather than below it.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the tables in a div, float them, and clear them. You should set a width on the divs so IE  doesn't break the floats.

Comment: No need for the DIVs. You can float the tables directly.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll run into sh!t in IE if you do. From the last time I did that.